# How to install texlive full on Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, latex

I want to install texlie on my Kali Linux. I run `apt-get install texlive-full` but I got this error message:

```
root@begueradj:~# sudo apt-get install texlive-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package texlive-full is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'texlive-full' has no installation candidate
```

How to install TexLive on Kali Linux ?

Note:

```
root@begueradj:~# cat /etc/issue
Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0 \n \l
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: most likely you are not up to date and the dependencies for this package have changed to more recent packaged (e.g. a kernel update). Did you try `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` yet?

Comment: @Fiximan Thank you, but I already did that

Comment: Paste the output of `apt-cache policy` into your question.

Comment: Just simply type 'sudo apt-get install texlive-full'.

Comment: Why would you want to run LaTeX typesetting on an OS designed for security experts?  https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Comment: @Kusalananda to write up a paper describing the latest vulnerability they found ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Duh, of course! My bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Sudo apt-get install kali-linux-all
```

The kali-linux-all package comes with texlive and much more

Usage 15 GB

```
apt-cache show kali-linux-all | grep depends
```

---

Or there's the simple version

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install texlive <- basic

 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

---

Or you can install the package alone

```
 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install texlive-base

 sudo apt-get install texlive-extra-utils 

 sudo apt-get install texlive-font-utils 

 sudo alt-get install texlive-generic-extra    

 sudo apt-get install texlive-pstricks-doc 

 sudo apt-get install texlive-pstricks

 sudo apt-get install sharutils

 sudo apt-get install texmaker

 sudo apt-get install texlive htmlxml

 sudo apt-get install texlive-generic-recommended   

 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra-doc

 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra

 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended

 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended-doc

 sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures

 sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures-doc

 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base

 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base-doc

 sudo apt-get install gv texlive-lang-all

 sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-english

 sudo apt-get install texlive-binaries

 sudo apt-get install gedit-latex-plugin

 sudo apt-get install latex-beamer texpower 

 sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra texpower-examples      imagemagick
```

Or simplify it even more with :

```
 apt-get build-dep texlive
```

---

```
  man  latex <- more info
```

Also see for instructions on use of latex for beginners

www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/editorandterminal.html

---

To remove

sudo apt-get --purge remove texlive*

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. download texlive image from [this link](http://ctan.asis.io/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2016.iso)
2. mount iso to somewhere:
   `mount <DOWNLOAD_PATH/texlive2016.iso /mnt>`
3. cd /mnt
4. ./install-tl
5. change options if needed
6. start installation process by  `I`